# List View C# stay selected

Tags: c#, listview, controls

I have a list view that after a double click, a record opens a new form to show the details, but the record in the list view lost the "selection"....
How do I know which record was clicked ???

Thanks

Maria João

Answer (score 37):

The listview control has a *HideSelection* property that defaults to True.  Set this to False and the current row will remain highlighted even if the control loses focus.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the HideSelection property on the list view to false. It's enabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the selection will turn "gray" when focus is lost, and "blue" when focused.  Keeping it blue when the focus is lost is more difficult ... you'll have to override the ListView::DrawItem